# Virtual Box Fix

Tags: windows

I have used the Utilman trick to login do to defaultuser 0 being made. I made my own account and deleted default user zero but when I sign in it just brings me to cortana, then says taking longer than expected, then fails. I cant shift F10 because, it change that to Utilman! Help! What do I do

Comment: Try a Repair Install from the Windows 10 Media Creation Link. That is what I would do in this case.

Comment: where would i get that? Also maybe can you make a new vm and link a vdi file that is unlicensed so its is not illegal through medafire meaybe

Comment: Here is the MCL:   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10   .  Your Windows 10 machine needs to be running, use a browser to load the link and choose the second link down.  Try to run it in place.

Comment: so download tool now? Thats what I made the iso with, also I killed msoobe and logonui and it seemed to work but then I got critical_proccess_died

Comment: You may have really corrupted your machine. You may need to make a new one.

Comment: but I made snapshots everytime I did anything risky I killed logonui and saw a desktop  for a second, does that help me do anything

Comment: Can you blend a past snapshot? I use VMware not VBOX but the concept is the same. I make a good machine, and back it up before doing anything risky. Snapshots are not backups so I do not depend on them.

Comment: You mean restore? And is there a way to skip OOBE entirely? Like i have a taskbar and it shows my programs but i also have login open, killing it just reopens

Comment: Snapshots can be combined to the main virtual machine . They are not system restores.